# Dot and Cross Product Proof: $u \times (v \times w) = ( u \cdot w)v - (u \cdot v)w$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, cross-product

How do you prove that: $u \times (v \times w) = ( u \cdot w)v - (u \cdot v)w$ ?
The textbook says as a hint to "first do it for $u=i,j$ and $k$; then write $u-xi+yj+zk$ but I am not sure what that means.

Comment: I am also not sure how to expand the right side of the equation

Comment: It means for you to do it to the unit vectors $\hat{i}=(1,0,0) ;\hat{j}=(0,1,0) ; and \hat{k}=(0,0,1)$.

Comment: so you let u=i v=j and w=k? :S

Comment: No, let $\textbf{u}$ be each one separately, that is, carry out the calculation 3 times with respect to each of the orthonormal basis vectors.

Comment: Do you mean "write $u = xi+yj+zk$"?

Comment: How do you carry out (u⋅w)v?

Does it mean (u⋅w )⋅v?

Comment: No. What kind of object is $u \cdot w$?

Comment: a scalar... ohhh, I see

Comment: Yup. You might want to look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product if you get stuck.

Comment: im lost. I tried using the unit vectors for u and letting v= [v1 v2 v3] and w = w1 w2 w3] and i got different things for both sides

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to use the basic definitions of scalar and vector triple products to prove this. Let $\mathbf u= a_1 \mathbf i + a_2 \mathbf j + a_3 \mathbf k, \mathbf v= b_1 \mathbf i + b_2 \mathbf j + b_3 \mathbf k, \mathbf w= c_1 \mathbf i + c_2 \mathbf j + c_3 \mathbf k$,

Then $(\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{w})= (b_2c_3-b_3c_2) \mathbf i + (b_3c_1-b_1c_3) \mathbf j + (b_1c_2-b_2c_1) \mathbf k$

Hence, $\mathbf{u} \times (\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{w})= \begin{vmatrix}
\mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k}\\
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
(b_2c_3-b_3c_2) & (b_3c_1-b_1c_3) & (b_1c_2-b_2c_1) \end{vmatrix}$

=$(a_1c_1+a_2c_2+a_3c_3)(b_1 \mathbf{i}+ b_2 \mathbf{j} + b_3 \mathbf{k}) - (a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3)(c_1 \mathbf{i}+ c_2 \mathbf{j} + c_3 \mathbf{k})$

=$( \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{w}) \cdot \mathbf{v} - (\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}) \cdot \mathbf{w}$

Comment: How did you get the second part

Doesnt 

Hence, u×(v×w)= det  i          a1        b2c3-b3c2       
                                  J         a2         - b3c1+b1c3 
                                  K         a3         b1c2-b2c1

Comment: Second part is the formula for vector triple product. It's a determinant, with the first row consisting of unit vectors, second row of the components of u, and third row of the components of (v x w)

Comment: isnt it supposed to be the columns that have the first column as unit vectors, second as the components of u and 3rd column the components of vxw?

Comment: I've always done it as rows, so I don't know about the column one. But since it's a determinant, that should also give you the same result.